# Do I need somehow "prepare" my HTML before moving on to making my page more sexy with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Do I need somehow "prepare" my HTML before moving on to making my page more sexy with jQuery?

What I mean is there some rule that says that HTML modification with jQuery is easier when HTML has "this" and "that" and "that too"? Some "HTML design patterns" like we have in C++ for example?

My HTML is generated by PHP application from templates and data retrieved from mySql database, and it is styled with CSS so I have ids and classes and almost all "components" on pages are inside divs (with id or class or both) so I presume that it is "jQuery ready" but maybe I should add something more to HTML or think about something?

I mostly have a complete vision what I want to accomplish with jQuery and how page should look like and behave when I finish so it is "only" matter of implementing it but I don't want to get too deep and suddenly discover that if I done something at the beginning my work would be easier and faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One advice: generate [valid HTML](http://validator.w3.org/) according to whatever DOCTYPE you are using and have fun with jquery. Also avoid mixing markup and javascript: keep them separate and progressively enhance your markup with javascript features.

Comment: so all I need is valid HTML and I can start to mess it around with jQuery? cool :)

Comment: technically you don't even need valid html, but it will probably save a lot of headaches if you do make it valid

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is create a bare HTML page that is usable as-is, meaning, no Javascript required to operate it – that's the ideal anyway, building a web app usually means there's a dependency on Javascript, but you should only use JS when necessary.

Adding Javascript should only enhance your UI while CSS should add the presentation on top of the existing HTML structure. In other words, an HTML page without CSS and Javascript should look and read well.

Comment: that is exactly what I have now: pure HTML with few CSS rules and it works completely without scripts. at the same time it is so ugly that causes blindness among my users so I want to make it cool and pretty with some jQuery magic :)